# How do I split a SVG shape into several shapes in Java or Processing?

Tags: java, svg, processing

For example, given a circle SVG shape with five points located equidistantly on it.  I want to split the circle into five arcs based upon those points. In the image below, one of those arcs is in red.  How do I go about doing that?  In particular, I would like to use the [geomerative](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/) library (from Processing), but would open to other solutions in Java as well.

[image: circle split into 5 equal arcs]

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply draw the five arcs using Processing's [arc()](http://processing.org/reference/arc_.html) function ?
You just need to keep count of the 72 degrees angle increment for each of the 5 sections:

```
int sides = 5;
//360 degrees / 5 sides, but in radians (what arc() likes)
float angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
float diameter = 350;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  colorMode(HSB,sides,100,100);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(30);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
}
void draw(){
  background(0,0,100);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < sides; i++){
    //72 degrees * each side to which we subtract a 90 degrees offset to first point is towards the top, not the side
    float angle = (angleIncrement * i)-HALF_PI;

    stroke(i,100,100);
    arc(200,200,diameter,diameter,angle,angle+angleIncrement);
  }
}
```

[image: circle split into 5 equal arcs]
You can actually run this as demo bellow:

```js
var sides = 5;
//360 degrees / 5 sides, but in radians (what arc() likes)
var angleIncrement;
var diameter = 350;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  colorMode(HSB,sides,100,100);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(30);
  strokeCap(SQUARE);
  
  angleIncrement = TWO_PI / sides;
}
function draw(){
  background(0,0,100);
  
  for(var i = 0 ; i < sides; i++){
    //72 degrees * each side to which we subtract a 90 degrees offset to first point is towards the top, not the side
    var angle = (angleIncrement * i)-HALF_PI;
    
    stroke(i,100,100);
    arc(200,200,diameter,diameter,angle,angle+angleIncrement);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```